# Expression must have a pointer-to-object reference (C++)

Tags: c++

I'm working on a bootloader, an I get this syntax error, and have no idea what it means, If someone could help me out, it would be much appreciated.

```
bool DrawBitmap(BYTE Bitmap, int x, int y, int w, int h)
{
    for(int i=0;i<=w;i++)
        for(int i2=0;i2<=h; i2++)
        {
            setpixel(i+x,i2+h, Bitmap[(((w*i2)-1)+i)]);
        }
}
```

Note, the error occurs in `[(((w*i2)-1)+i)]`.

Comment: what is the syntax error?  and why does this have an assembly tag? maybe you want the c++ tag and perhaps specify the compiler and add that tag (gcc, llvm, etc).

Comment: By "italicized" you mean the square brackets, right? If so, I'm guessing, `BYTE` is probably `typedef`'ed or `#define`'d `char`. You can't dereference `Bitmap` if it's not a pointer. You probably want `BYTE* Bitmap`.

Comment: Italics don't work in code tags. Are the two asterisks supposed to mark the italicized code?

Comment: Unless `BYTE` has an overloaded `operator[]`, you need `BYTE*`. Note: `BYTE&` cannot be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bitmap is passed as a BYTE.  Probably it should be a BYTE-pointer.

Try defining your function like this:

```
bool DrawBitmap(BYTE *Bitmap, int x, int y, int w, int h)
{  
    for(int i=0;i<=w;i++)  
        for(int i2=0;i2<=h; i2++)  
        {  
            setpixel(i+x,i2+h, Bitmap[(((w*i2)-1)+i)]);
        }  
}
```

Comment: Yes, realized this, fixed it, but I don't know how to delete a question :$